# Login application - redirect to another page on click on submit button

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

When I am running index.html its opening but on clicking the submit button in login page I need it to redirect to another page such that validation happens in the redirected page and it displays something.

Suppose the login page opens with this url

```
http://localhost:51499/index.html
```

I enter credentials and click on submit button. I need it to redirect to another url to do the validations there and throw success message. Currently on clicking submit button is redirecting to a blank page but not the next url.

My angular code:

```
     angular.module('Project', [])
          .controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$location', function ($scope, $http) {
              $scope.login = function (emailId, password) {

                  var uri = 'http://localhost:64367/api/Project/ValidateLogin/' + emailId + "/" + password;

                  $http.get(uri).then(function (data) {

                          if(data)
                          {
   $location.path("/forgotpassword");

                              } 
                          else {
                              alert("Error!!!");
                          //return;
                           }
                  });

              }
                  }])
```

Route config code is here:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('Project', [ 'ngRoute']);


// configure our routes
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        //In the above configuration, when user is idle for 900s (does not move mouse, press any key or button etc), 
        $routeProvider
            // route for the login page
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: '../view/login.html',
                controller: 'loginCtrl'
            })     
         .when('/forgotpassword', {
             templateUrl: '../view/ForgotPassword.html',
             controller: 'forgotPasswordCtrl'
         })

}]);
```

Error message:
[image]

Comment: What error message do you get in console?

Comment: you cannot pass as such in uri, use stateParams. $state.go('your validation state', stateParams); (stateParams is an object with values)

Comment: Why can't you do the validations in same page? Why do you want to go to another page only to validate the credentials?

Comment: @Sharmila I agree with you. I think he miss the config section. Once he'll configure the route then only he can achieve this

Comment: @RameshRajendran route is configured already. When I am clicking on submit button its redirecting to a blank page. I am not sure if its validating also or not

Comment: validation should happen in the different url "http://localhost:64367/api/Project/ValidateLogin/"

Comment: Can you post the route config section? did you configure the validatelogin controller in your rout config section?

Comment: @ramesh rajendran Yes i did just now. Please check

Comment: That is the main issue. where you configure the `HtmlPage1.html` and the relevant controller in the route like as logincontroller?

Comment: @RameshRajendran i created HtmlPage1.html just to check if my code is entering into angular success part. contains just a text. Am i doing this wrong? what should i write in success part to check if the code is entering if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create a new JS file for validatelogin controller and configure it with appropriate view(htmlpage1) same as login configuration.

```
.when('/login', {
                templateUrl: '../view/login.html',
                controller: 'loginCtrl'
            })  
.when('/validatelogin, {
                templateUrl: '../view/HtmlPage1.html',
                controller: 'validateloginCtrl'
            })
```

also you need write this code 
`$location.path("/validatelogin")` instead of `$location.URL('http://localhost:51499/view/HtmlPage1.html');`

Here is a sample article about this : [Redirect to the original requested page after login using AngularJs](http://nadeemkhedr.com/redirect-to-the-original-requested-page-after-login-using-angularjs/)

Comment: I tried the exact same thing but with another controller I had in route config. It still gives the blank page

Comment: and did you write this code? `$location.path("/routname")` route name which is define you in the routconfig section / or post full configuration then I will give the solutions

Comment: i made changes . Please have a look.

Comment: See your error showing about `maincontroller`. You should be define that `controller` in config section like as other controller configuration

Comment: I have even tried /forgetpassword. Just to try as it already has everything set. Please check the whole of edited code. This error i got after trying what you suggested

Comment: Yup. that's good. I think you have conflict the code with the controller. did you use `maincontroller` anywhere in your application?  find and let me know

Comment: mainController is one of the js files which is included in index.html

Comment: But you didn't configure that in config section.

Comment: But how that will affect my side of code? Someone else is working on it. He has commented that part of route config . I uncommented it and tried. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Just remove the reference maincontroller script from the index.html page and then try it :)

Comment: Tried that too :D no help. And getting the same error in console

Comment: See I have an idea, press ctrl+shift+F and put maincontroller click find all . it's showing if you use maincontroller in anywhere. if you used it then remove it that place.  :+1